# Reprocessing images of different versions in Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, carrierwave

Using Carrierwave, I created 3 versions of an avatar - an original, a small_thumb and a large_thumb using the following lines:

```
process :resize_to_limit => [400, 400]  

   version :big_thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [80, 80]
   end

   version :small_thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
   end
```

I added an additional method in my AvatarUploader class:

```
def reprocess(x,y,w,h)
        manipulate! do |img|
            img.crop(x.to_i, y.to_i, w.to_i, h.to_i, true) 

            end
resize_to_limit(180,180)  
end
```

which is called in my model after an update is performed:

```
attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
after_update :reprocess_image, :if => :cropping?

def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
end

private

def reprocess_image
image.reprocess(crop_x,crop_y,crop_w,crop_h)

end
```

I have managed to crop and resize the original version, but I can't seem to update the 2 thumbnails along with it.  I tried a few different techniques to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try

```
image.recreate_versions!
```

Sorry, on the bus. I can't expound on that.

Comment: `Model.all.each {|m| m.avatar.recreate_versions!}` Will work great if you have added a new version to a model with pre-existing records.

Comment: You may also need to call `save` on the model. At least I did. Might depend on your application configuration... so something like this worked for me: `Model.all.each {|m| m.avatar.recreate_versions!; m.save! }`

Comment: no need to apologize. just what I needed. bus coding a-ok.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `image.cache_stored_file!` before calling `recreate_versions!`

It's weird because the method itself calls that if the file is cached, but for some reason it wasn't working.

So that would be something like:

```
def reprocess_image
  image.reprocess(crop_x, crop_y, crop_w, crop_h)
  image.cache_stored_file!
  image.recreate_versions!
end
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. is it possible because I'm storing the images on SC3 with fog?

Comment: @kibaekr right, you'll need to download the image, reprocess it and then reupload it.

Comment: for me doing something like this worked: "image.recreate_versions! unless image.blank?" inside the loop. I didn't have to download the images, I just did it in the console

Answer (score 3):

This HowTo was most helpful for me (even if I don't use fog):

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Recreate-and-reprocess-your-files-stored-on-fog

I added a reprocess method on my model and then called it in for each loop in my rake task:

```
  def reprocess
    begin
      self.process_photo_upload = true
      self.photo.cache_stored_file!
      self.photo.retrieve_from_cache!(photo.cache_name)
      self.photo.recreate_versions!
      self.save!
    rescue => e
      STDERR.puts  "ERROR: MyModel: #{id} -> #{e.to_s}"
    end
  end
```

Rake:

`task :reprocess_photos => :environment do
  MyModel.all.each{|mm| mm.reprocess}
end`

PS: Rails 4.2

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but maybe putting something like.

```
def reprocess_image
  image.reprocess(crop_x,crop_y,crop_w,crop_h)
  image.recreate_versions!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

check this latest RailsCast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised

after cropping one version of the image, you can then either calculate the cropping coordinates for the other versions, or probably easier, scale down the cropped image with the same aspect ratios as the other versions of the original image